# My 2008 MacBook keeps crashing and restarting

Tags: macbook-pro

Every day when I am working, or if I attempt to play a movie using my Mac, it will restart. It seems like every time it is about to restart the fan starts spinning pretty heavily and then it will crash and restart and put up a report. How do I fix this?

```
Anonymous UUID:       F08B596D-ACE9-F093-2190-993F0FBC3563

Sun Jan 19 11:03:01 2014
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff80090dc19e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8af7396c, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffef7f8af999b8, CR3: 0x000000000bd93000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660
RAX: 0x0fffff4e90010000, RBX: 0xffffef7f8af999b0, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x00000b16ffe93f6a
RSP: 0xffffff8081203d80, RBP: 0xffffff8081203e70, RSI: 0x00000b36ffe8c31b, RDI: 0xffffff807ba85148
R8:  0x00000000e0000000, R9:  0x0000000000000005, R10: 0x0000000000004722, R11: 0xffffff8009689ce8
R12: 0xffffff8013f47800, R13: 0x0000000000000005, R14: 0xffffff807ba85148, R15: 0xffffff7f8af97e20
RFL: 0x0000000000010006, RIP: 0xffffff7f8af7396c, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffef7f8af999b8, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x1

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8081203a10 : 0xffffff8009022f69 
0xffffff8081203a90 : 0xffffff80090dc19e 
0xffffff8081203c60 : 0xffffff80090f3606 
0xffffff8081203c80 : 0xffffff7f8af7396c 
0xffffff8081203e70 : 0xffffff7f8af72b89 
0xffffff8081203f30 : 0xffffff80090dda5c 
0xffffff8081203f50 : 0xffffff800903757a 
0xffffff8081203f90 : 0xffffff80090378c8 
0xffffff8081203fb0 : 0xffffff80090d6aa7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement(216.0)[A6EE4D7B-228E-3A3C-95BA-10ED6F331236]@0xffffff7f8af70000->0xffffff7f8af9afff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13B42

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D9369E3-D0A5-31B6-8D16-BFFBBB390393
Kernel slide:     0x0000000008e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8009000000
System model name: MacBook5,1 (Mac-F42D89C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 62816487879517
last loaded kext at 1570641829197: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs  2.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8b363000, size 335872)
last unloaded kext at 718429418555: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.2.1b2 (addr 0xffffff7f8b363000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.nvidia.CUDA 1.1.0
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.11
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.4.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.9.5
com.apple.nvenet    2.0.21
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.12
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.4fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.0f6
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.1.8
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.1.8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.5.1d27
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.6d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  650.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   600.34
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 650.4.4
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.10
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  21
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

System Profile:
Model: MacBook5,1, BootROM MB51.007D.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.32f8
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3231554538424453302D444A2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3231554538424453302D444A2D4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK1653GSX, 160.04 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS21N
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please use code formatting for log output! I've edited your post in an attempt to add code formatting, but if I've not formatted it correctly please re-edit.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you are getting a kernel panic when the machine is attempting to do something to the power management, which would correspond with your report of fan noise before the crash.

First step would be to reset the `System Management Controller`

Instructions for doing that are in this Apple support note :-

[Intel-based Macs: Resetting the System Management Controller (SMC)](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964)

Then try running Apple Hardware Test by rebooting with the <kbd>D</kbd> down - details are here :- http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509

Then check to see if the hard drive will verify - a bad drive could have corrupted the System.

If that doesn't work I'd try running off a System on an external drive for a day or two to see if it is a corrupt system on a good hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your GPU is dead or faulty. Try to use an app called gfxCardstatus and switch to Intel graphics. Then play a movie and see the issue is still there or gone.